# Router vuejs render the route in a different component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm making an app using laravel 8 and Vuejs.
Vue-router helps me to render the routes into the component < router-view >. It's working fine. The issue I'm running into comes when I render the Login and Register components that are completely different to the rest of the app.
I want to render < router-view > together with < header > and a < sidebar > but my Login and Register components must not be render with any  or .
How can I call and render Login and Register "outside" ?

Dashboard.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <header />
        <sidebar />
        <router-view></router-view>
    </v-app>
</template>
<script>
    export default{}
</script>
```

Login.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <Login />
    </v-app>
</template>
<script>
    export default{}
</script>
```

router.js

```
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
import Login from './components/Auth/Login.vue';
import Register from './components/Auth/Register.vue';
import App from './App.vue';

export const routes = [
    {
        name: 'Login',
        path: '/',
        component: Login
    },
    {
        name: 'Register',
        path: '/register',
        component: Register
    },
    {
        name: 'example-component',
        path: '/example',
        component: ExampleComponent
    },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define two layouts, one to be used when there is Auth, and one for when not. The one you posted will suite the Authenticated part, while for the not authenticated part, you should use a a different one where you won't have the header and sidebar.

Another way, would be to conditionally render the header and sidebar just when the user is logged in, but most likely, in your app, you'll have logic that shouldn't be available in not authorised paths.

Comment: It was so simple. That make sense. Also I've found this that it seems to be vue-router feature for exactly this subject. A condition on the sidebar and header looks like the simplest solution, thanks!
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views